# Windows Phone 7 Scheduled tasks running

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

As i understand i can launch a PeriodicTask from my windows phone application. But will it be called after application is terminated? Or, most important, will it be called by system after device reboot (before user run the main app next time)?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, they will run after a reboot and when your application is terminated but Battery Save Mode can prevent execution.

> Good introduction: 
>   http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/alexb/archive/2011/05/26/multi-tasking-in-windows-phone-7-1.aspx